# Facebook Invite not working in internet explorer

Tags: php, facebook

I have developed an application with invite functionality in php. It is working fine in mozilla but its not working in ie7. What is the reason behind it please help me on this?

Comment: What question is this? GIve us more info.

Comment: Please provide a code sample of the output. It sounds like an HTML/JavaScript issue.

Comment: Hi, i am using this code snippet may be this is not working 
$facebook = new Facebook($api_key, $secret); 
// $facebook->require_frame();
 //$user = $facebook->require_login();

Comment: Update the question, don't use comments.  I'm pretty sure that that code works in IE.  It must be something in your html in your login page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually IE has many problem. I am also fetching same problem, I have find a solution for it that explorer integrated with windows command, they can't get needed resources file ,while firefox updates everyday.

Comment: what _is_ the solution you found?